# error: variable might not have been initialized & if statement

Tags: java, class, variables, initialization, project

So basically, the

```
 //Black ops 2 Class generator Please help me FIX!!!!!!
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;
    public class money
        {
        public static void main(String[]args)
            {
        String primaryOption;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        Random primaryGen = new Random();

        String weaponType; //Rifle, SMG, HMG, Sniper, shotgun, or special
        String primaryoption; //Do you want a primary?
        String primaryWeapon; //The gun you get
        int primaryWeapon1; 
        String primrayCamo; //Camo for primary
        String MTAR = "MTAR", Type25 = "Type 25", SWAT556 = "SWAT-556", FALOSW = "FAL-OSW", M27 = "M27", SCARH = "SCAR-H", SMR = "SMR", M8A1 = "M8A1", AN94 = "AN-94";

        String secondaryOption; //Do you want a secondary?
        String secondaryWeapon; //Your gun
        int secondaryWeapon1;
        String secondaryCamo; //Camo for secondary
        System.out.println("Would you like a Primary Weapon? Yes(1) or No(2)");
        primaryOption = scan.nextLine();
            if (primaryOption.equals("Yes")) {
                System.out.println("Would you like a Rifle, SMG, HMG, Sniper, Shotgun, or Special?)");
                weaponType = scan.nextLine();
                    if (weaponType.equals("Rifle")) {
                        primaryWeapon1 = primaryGen.nextInt(1) +1;
                        if (primaryWeapon1 == 1) {
                            primaryWeapon = MTAR; //*&%&*This is where i initialized it.
    }
                return; 

                            }
    System.out.println("Primary Weapon: " + primaryWeapon); //This is where the error is. It say's im not initializing the variable but I initialize it in the last if statement
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: `String primaryWeapon = "Unarmed";`

Answer (score 1):

> It say's im not initializing the variable but I initialize it in the
>   last if statement

What happens if that "if" block is not executed? Then that variable will be un-assigned right? That is why compiler complaining.

Local variable should be assigned in all possible flows, otherwise it is compiletime error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the variable before you use it. If `if` statement fails, this variable will stay uninitialized:

```
 System.out.println("Primary Weapon: " + primaryWeapon);
```

So, where you declare it, equal it to `""`:

```
String primaryWeapon = ""; //The gun you get
```

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where `PrimaryWeapon` is never initialized (whenever `PrimaryWeapon1` is not equal to `1`).

Use this and it's fixed:

```
String primaryWeapon = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in this if statement:
Assuming you get here and weaponType does equal "rifle", it will return and exit your function. You should initialize your primaryWeapon to a default value, i.e. primaryWeapon = "None";

```
 if (weaponType.equals("Rifle")) {
                        primaryWeapon1 = primaryGen.nextInt(1) +1;
                        if (primaryWeapon1 == 1) {
                            primaryWeapon = MTAR; //*&%&*This is where i initialized it.
                        }
                        return; //<---- remove this
 }
```

Also complete the if block, `if(yes) {...} else {...}.`The java compiler will branch out conditional clauses, and will warn/error  when attempting to use unintialized variables. For example:

```
int b;
boolean f = true;
if(f)
    b =1;
System.out.println(b); //error because no else block


//Fixed
int b; 
boolean f = true;
if(f)
b = 1;
else
b= 2;
System.out.println(b);
```

--Niru